# React js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hello I'm trying to order data, using a function recursive, this's the function:

```
function orderRecursive(Data, tab="") {
    let orderData = [];
    for(const data of Data) {
     
        orderData.push({  
            id : data.id,
            name: tab + data.name,
            idfhater : data.idfahter
        });  

        const children = Data.filter( item => item.idfather === data.id);         
        if( children.length > 0 ){           
            orderData.push( orderRecursive(children, tab + "\t") );
        }
    }    
    return orderData
}
```

but I'm getting this trouble:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

is something like the function rcursive never end, but I have this condition if chlidren > 0 do it else nothing happend, so I don understand why is this happened?

Comment: one solution would be to change the data pattern after parsing. for example you could create a cat class with id field and children array field containing cats and then print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to parse data so that you have cat object containing other cat objects (quick solution).

```
// const data = provided data assuming cat id cannot loop indefinitely with father id

// this function creates a dependency tree of cats with root cats and all their children
function getChildren(childrenTree, cat={id: 0}, generation=0) {
    const children = []
    for(const child of childrenTree.filter(c => c.idfather === cat.id)) {
        child.children = getChildren(childrenTree.filter(c => c.idfather !== cat.id), child, generation + 1)
        child.generation=generation
        children.push(child)
    }

    return children
    
}


// this function parses the dependency tree so it prints out whatr you want
function printCats(children, tab="") {
    let value = ""
    for(const cat of children) {
        value += tab + cat.description + "\n";
        if(cat.children.length > 0)
            value += printCats(cat.children, tab+"\t")
    }

    return value
}

console.log(printCats(getChildren(data)))
```

### IMPROVEMENTS

a much quicker option would be to combine the 2 above functions into one:

```
function printChildren(childrenTree, cat={id: 0}, tab="") {
    let childrenStr = ""
    for(const child of childrenTree.filter(c => c.idfather === cat.id)) {
        childrenStr += `${tab}${child.description}\n`
        childrenStr += printChildren(childrenTree.filter(c => c.idfather !== cat.id), child, tab + "\t")
    }

    return childrenStr
    
}

console.log(printChildren(data))
```

both these codes print out:

```
Cat
Cat 1
        Cat 1.1
        Cat 1.2
Cat 2
        Cat 2.1
                Cat 2.1.1
                Cat 2.1.2
                        Cat 2.1.2.1
Cat 3
```

this code uses recursivity and shall be safe. However, you should always double check any code using recursivity as it may overload your memory and crash your program

Comment: hi! bro! this work  so much, but I'm having a troble whit  size exceeded

Comment: thought i double checked this program but apparently not, there might be some kind of useless looping in the getChildren function, try to debug it, i'll try to debug it to

Comment: thanks bro!! I'm debunning it..... I'm trying to divide it in two function(father and children), but I' was same error.... let me work it

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain probelm. this problem is linked to memory and the way objects are stored in memory in javascript. That's why i separated the creation of dependency tree from the print function. You rae in some way pushing orderData in tiself indefinitely. when using reecursivity you shall always be aware of that. pushing in arrays is not the best thing you may do. Moreover, why would you change the name of the cat. isn't it easier to add a generation field ?

Comment: @DeepMind the improved answer should do the trick fine. I just reworked my dependency tree so it printed out the string instead of an object